# Replacing credit card numbers from a memo field in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, masking

I have a string from a memo field with some credit cards on it and I want to mask the numbers to show only the last 4 digits. Example:

```
<cfset str = "Her card no. is 1234567890123456 which is a bogus number.">
```

How can I make the value of the str to read:

> Her card no. is ************3456 which is a bogus number.

Comment: Instead of masking, try some text like "Her card number ending in 3456 which is a bogus number". Masking with asterisk characters at the very least leaks meta info about the card, namely the type of card. 

And I'm curious about the context of this software that is storing full credit card numbers. I don't want to jump to conclusions but PCI compliance red flags are going up.

Comment: Just like @SamM I'm concerned that you are dealing with credit card numbers. There are many laws and requirements surrounding credit cards, social security numbers, etc. So much so that there are some very large companies that only use third party components from companies like Stripe and other payment gateways so the data never actually passes through their servers not to mention get saved so a hacker could access or misconfigured web page outputs.

Comment: I'll first reiterate Adrian's answer and say that you shouldn't store credit card numbers. Second, if you must mask sensitive information, don't do it in ColdFusion. Do it on the SQL server itself through whatever query you're using. Then the data is never in transit in an unmasked format. Plus, it less processing to mask it through the query.

Comment: @Swawn Actually masking CC info in ColdFusion is better than waiting to do it later with SQL server... especially since 1) some info may not get databased and be sent instantly via email, 2) you can sanitize it prior to ever hitting the database server and 3) ensure that only credit card numbers are masked and not cc-like values (like Instagram or GooglePlus URL parameters.)

Comment: @francoom I shared my solution (below) and am using it in production.  I also added a link so you can experiment with it using CFTry.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. You may need to alter the regex digit match maximum, depending on your credit card number range:

**UPDATED 02.07.18**

```
<cfset str = "Her card no. is 1234567890123456 which is a bogus number.">
<cfset maskall = true>

<cfset regex = ".*[\s]+([0-9]{8,19})[\s]+.*">

<cfset ccNumberProtected = "">

<cfif REFindNoCase(regex,str)>
  <cfset ccNumber = REReplaceNoCase(str,regex,"\1")>
  <cfif maskall>
    <cfset ccNumberProtected = RepeatString("*",Len(ccNumber))>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset ccNumberProtected = RepeatString("*",Len(ccNumber) - 4) & Right(ccNumber,4)>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<cfif Len(Trim(ccNumberProtected))>
  <cfset str = "Her card no. is " & ccNumberProtected & " which is a bogus number.">
<cfelse>
  <cfset str = "Card number could not be displayed for security reasons">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Different credit cards companies use different formatting (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number). This only works in very specific situations. If this regex fails, which it will in many cases, the credit card number will show up as plain text. Using regex to mask the credit card number like this, is not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: I am just answering the OPs question, on a code level. I agree that obfuscating CC numbers is a bad idea, in general, but I try not too make assumptions, about an OPs wider objectives.

Comment: Actually, I want to mask all 16 digit numbers from a textarea field. We currently have a support page where customers can enter comments. Some of them are entering their whole card number and I want to mask it before it gets appended into a table. Thanks.

Comment: @francoom My answer will mask all but the last 4 digits of CC numbers between 8 - 19 in length. This range matches all possible CC number lengths. I will add an update to my answer to mask all digits.

Comment: Hi Charles. I want the whole text area field or string be in one variable. So that everything will be in one variable. Example: <cfoutput>#str#</cfoutput> will give you the same string but with the mask numbers. Thanks.

Comment: @ francoom My routine does add everything into one variable. It will give you the textarea content, but with sensitive data masked. Have you tried running my code? I am pretty sure it does what you want, but, if it doesn't, please could you provide some more details about what you require and I will update it. For example, provide me with the input string and all possible output strings, and I will create a new custom routine for you.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I make the value of the str to read:
>
> Her card no. is ************3456 which is a bogus number.

Simple:

**STOP SAVING CREDIT CARD NUMBERS IN A TEXT FIELD!**

This is a PCI Compliance nightmare. This practice could cause your company to no longer process online payments when you get audited.

You need to stop this asap AND initiate a project to scrub unencrypted CC numbers from all previous entires like this. If you are saving their CC numbers elsewhere in your system, you need to only save the last 4 digits. You can then reference that field in your message.

When comments / memos are saved anywhere, you need to scrub the data for number patterns matching CC number, bank routing/account and social security numbers.

This looks like something from a production support ticket, so I'd urge you to  change this practice asap. If the CC they have on file is bogus, then just say so in your memo:

> The card number currently on file is invalid.

Comment: I store website form submissions to a database. (Any PCI-sensitive data is masked before the data is logged.)  We recently audited the data and used a regex to scan for credit cards that may have been submitted in comment fields.  We found that many Instagram and GooglePlus URL parameters match the credit card regex.  Only one value was identified, but there were many false positives. 

SUMMARY: Don't blindly scrub regex matches in your database unless it is actually a credit card or you could end up destroying important non-CC data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get the numbers as you have asked in the question. This will even change the numbers dynamically.

```
<cfset str="Her card no. is 1234567890123456  which is a bogus number.">
<cfset num=listGetAt(str,5,' ')>
<cfset card=right(num,4)>
<cfset card=listInsertAt(card,1,'************')>
<cfset card=listChangeDelims(card,'')>
<cfset card=replaceList(str,num,card)>
<cfdump var="#card#" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came up with a different solution and later found this question while searching for other solutions. My initial regex didn't detect all credit card formats (space, dash, no spaces) and incorrectly masked Instagram & GooglePlus URLs, but this one works well and uses the Luhn algorithm to only modify actual credit card values.

Check out the blog entry for a live, editable demo using either Adobe ColdFusion or Lucee.
https://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/176823552659/mask-credit-card-numbers-using-coldfusion

```
<cfscript>
function maskCC(textFragment){
    var response = Javacast("string", arguments.textFragment);
    var temp = {};
    temp.TestCCs = reMatch("\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b", response);
    if (arrayLen(temp.TestCCs)){
        for (temp.thisCC in temp.TestCCs) {
            temp.cleanNum = reReplace(temp.thisCC,"[^[:digit:]]","","all");
            if( isValid("creditcard", Temp.cleanNum )){
                response = Replace(response, temp.thisCC, "************" & Right(Temp.cleanNum,4), "all");
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
</cfscript>

<CFOUTPUT>
<pre>
#maskCC('4444 3333 2222 1111')# (with spaces)
#maskCC('4444-3333-2222-1111')# (with dashes)
#maskCC('4444333322221111')# (no separators)
#maskCC('1234567890123456')# (not a CC)

GENERIC TEXT FROM TEXTAREA FORM FIELD:
#maskCC('Here is my unsecure CCNum: 4444333322221111.
My transaction ID IS: 4567123498765283. Please refund.')#
</pre>
</CFOUTPUT>
```